# CLion Target is Not Specified-No Targets

Tags: c++, cmake, arduino, clion

Still spinning back up on C++ after a long absence. I have an Arduino project that I can't do google test in because it screws with the Arduino plugin, so I created a separate test project.

In this test project, I have three dirs...lib, src, and tst. The lib dir contains third party libs, in this case, google test. The src dir contains a couple of test specific pieces of code and sym links to the src in the other project. The tst directory contains the unit tests.

This is working on my desktop at home, but I'm on client site and trying to get the tests to work. The config screen looks like:

[image]

and I can't select any targets.

Here is my root CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(ProcessControllerTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include_directories(src)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(tst)
add_subdirectory(lib/googletest)
```

Here is the src one:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(BINARY ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES LIST_DIRECTORIES true *.h *.cpp)

set(SOURCES ${SOURCES})

add_executable(${BINARY}_run ${SOURCES})

add_library(${BINARY}_lib STATIC ${SOURCES})
```

and here is the tst one.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(BINARY ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_tst)

file(GLOB_RECURSE TEST_SOURCES LIST_DIRECTORIES false *.h *.cpp)

set(SOURCES ${TEST_SOURCES})

add_executable(${BINARY} ${TEST_SOURCES})

add_test(NAME ${BINARY} COMMAND ${BINARY})

target_link_libraries(${BINARY} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_lib gmock)
target_link_libraries(${BINARY} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_lib gtest)
```

Tried google, not much there. Nothing helpful.

The main.cpp in my src doesn't run either. No targets for the src directory.

When I try to do Build Project, it says "cannot find any cmake profile"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was evidently a toolchain question. I need to install cygwin with g++, gdb and make and that seems to have fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that the initial build wasn't successful
I re-ran it and all CMake targets were added.
[image]